# Calling other programs using system() in C++

Tags: c++

I am practicing C++ using the book "Thinking in C++: Volume 1" by Bruce Eckel.  In it is a little program that uses the system() command to call other programs.  I have already compiled a script "Hello.cpp" with the object file "Hello" in my practice folder.  The code I am trying to get to work can be found on page 108 of the book (which is free on the internet, just Google the title and author), and goes as follows:

```
//: cplusplus:CallHello.cpp
// Call another program
#include <cstdlib> //Declare "system()"
using namespace std;

int main (){
    system("Hello");
}///:~
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
sh: 1: Hello: not found
```

"Hello.cpp" is in the directory, and has associated object file "Hello", which runs perfectly fine.  What's wrong here?

EDIT: Attempted resolutions to the problem that didn't work are as follows:  Changing to "Hello.o" or "Hello.exe"; changing the included header file from  to .

EDIT:  After more thorough reading, I discovered why the code didn't work.  Basically, the argument of the function system() executes a command on the command line.

Comment: What OS do you use? Also, you say that your 'Hello' app 'runs perfectly fine'. How *do* you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess on my part but try system("./Hello");

It smells like a pathing problem.

And the bin you want to run is "Hello" and not, say, "Hello.exe" or "Hello.a" or "Hello.elf" or whatever, yes?

Comment: "And the bin you want to run is "Hello" and not, say, "Hello.exe" or "Hello.a" or "Hello.elf" or whatever, yes?" You see, I don't actually know, I am a TOTAL novice

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I am still wondering why Eckel had the code that way in his book.

Comment: Go into the directory where your Hello binary is. Do a "dir" or an "ls" or whatever your system expects. What's the full name of the file? Does it show up as having an extension, maybe?

Try the ./ thing first though. Let's eliminate that, and we can troubleshoot more if that doesn't fix it all up.

Comment: @user2596226 Eckel seemed to think he was executing a bin file that was in /usr/bin or something similar

Comment: Glad it worked. Probably on Eckel's system the environment is different from yours. There are lots of different OSes and shells and so on, after all....

Comment: @TheJoker I did a "dir" and the file "Hello" appears in the listing without an extension.  What precisely does this mean?

Comment: It means You're probably on a *NIX system of some sort that doesn't rely on file extensions to decide how to run an executable. Well, that's my guess.

Comment: @user2596226 It means the bin "Hello" exists in the Present Working Directory and you are specifying the pathname using "./" to execute it

Comment: For UNIX-like systems, it depends on whether the current directory `.` is in your `$PATH`. The book may have assumed that you do, but in fact it's now considered best practice *not* to have `.` in `$PATH` due to the risk of running unexpected commands.

Answer (score 0):

If Hello is an executable file, Then use system("./Hello");
 and it doesn't matter if you have the source code in the directory to execute the executable